# laravel 5.6 - vue component rendered twice in the extended section of blade

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

In my latest `laravel 5.6` project, I use `vue` and `blade` together.
I have a situation that, if I put my `vue component` in extended `blade.php` file, that `vue component` will be rendered twice.

For example:

layouts/app.blade.php:

```
<div id="app">
...
<mobilesidebar></mobilesidebar>{{-- vue component --}}
...
</div>
<script src="/js/manifest.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

stores/show.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
...
<storelayout></storelayout>{{-- vue component --}}
...
@endsection
```

I will get:
[image]

but if i move `storelayout` to `layouts/app.blade.php`:

```
    <div id="app">
    ...
    <mobilesidebar></mobilesidebar>{{-- vue component --}}
    <storelayout></storelayout>{{-- vue component --}}
    ...
    </div>
```

Everything become normal.

I believe it has to do with `app.js` somehow call the `render` function twice.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: in which element do you mount your vue app?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim In the `app.blade.php`.

Comment: usually i use this syntax: `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>` and in the child template :`@section('content')
    @parent` in the parent one : `<div id="app"> @yield('content') ... `

Comment: I just discovered  a very silly things I did. I use `@yield('content')` twice in the `app.blade.php` because I thought I want to split out the code for web and mobile. That is why `vue component` at the `@extend` is rendered twice.

Comment: oow, good news my bro